# ipad refresh the tab when clicked submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

actually m using desktop and ipad..in desktop browser when i click on submit button the page in ipad browser should get refreshed...
suppose in desktop browser i have created a file test1.php

```
<input type="submit" value= "submit"/>
```

when i click on submit button the page in ipad should get refreshed that is refresh.php

i have tried the following code

```
<a href="rand_num.php" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.href); return false">link</a>
```

this works fine in desktop browser but the same in ipad is not getting refreshed

Comment: If you are already using an anchor, why do you utilize a click event instead of setting the anchor to the correct target?

Comment: becoz if u use window.open it opens in a new tab

Comment: which is the same as `target="_blank"`…

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an submit button just to refresh a page, you could use this:

```
<form target='test1.php'>
    <input type='text' name='text1'>
    <input type='button' value='submit'>
</form>
```

This will refresh the page, going to, lets say test1.php?text1=[whatever your text may be]
You can then use php to retrieve the value as $_GET['text1']